# Getting Boost 1.68 working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, boost-asio, ubuntu-18.04

I want to use Boost 1.68 on Ubuntu 18.04. I noticed the Boost/libboost package available on Ubuntu is only 1.65, so I found a resource that suggested the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove libboost-all-dev
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mhier/libboost-latest
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libboost1.68
```

However, after running this I no longer have the boost include files in my `/usr/include` directory. If I do `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, it seems I can only add 1.65.1

**Is there a way I can get boost and the include files from 1.68 to run on Ubuntu 18.04?**

I'm still relatively new to Linux/ubuntu so perhaps I'm overlooking something simple? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: As of today, seems that installing from source is the only option, couldn't find any reliable package provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By installing `libboost1.68` you only install Boost library files. Header files are at `libboost1.68-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libboost1.68-dev
```

Comment: I get `Unable to locate package libboost1.68-dev`...

Comment: @kebs, did you add the repository beforehand and update package index files? I just checked on a pure docker image and it works.

Comment: Yep, but the ones I wanted fail to build, see https://launchpad.net/~mhier/+archive/ubuntu/libboost-latest/+packages. But anyway, I finally build 1.75 from source, isn't actually that hard, went pretty much uneventfull.